# Why does my Scala enumeration break when I move it to another package?

Tags: scala

Enumeration code looks like the following

```
package com.mydomain

object Market extends Enumeration {

  type Market = Value
  val ASX, LSE = Value 

}
```

I try to use as follows

```
import com.mydomain.Market._
```

.
.
.

```
if (Market.ASX == currentMarket) {
...
}
```

This was working when everything was in the same package.  When I moved to a new package I now get

not found: value Market

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you import `Market`, you have `ASX` and `LSE` *directly* available to you.  You don't have `Market.ASX` available--that would be if you had object `Market` available, which is what would happen if you did `import com.mydomain._`.

Being inside package `com.mydomain` causes `com.mydomain._` to be loaded just like you imported it, so that's why you can say `Market.ASX` when you're in the same package.

When you write code in a different package, you need to either `import com.mydomain._` and then use `Market.ASX`, or `import com.mydomain.Market._` and then use `ASX`.